# Should I reinstall Ubuntu or there is another way?

Tags: wireless, 18.04, sound

I have Ubuntu 18.04.
Occasionally my laptop can not connect to WiFi.
I tried a lot of answers but none works for me.
Yesterday I tried to play a video I know that has sound but it was silent.
Should I reinstall Ubuntu or there's another way to make things run?
I tried

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
```

I have Broadcom for WiFi.

for audio system

```
sudo apt install ubuntu-restricted-extras
```

then `pavucontrol`
I didn't find it so I run `sudo apt install pavucontrol`

For WiFi 
`sudo update-pciids
sudo apt install firmware-b43-installer`
 Then Reboot the laptop and every thing is fine.

Answer (score 0):

I think there are two different (and independent) problems:

- **Wifi** - it is important to use the correct proprietary driver for your model of Broadcom hardware. See this link,

  [Installing Broadcom Wireless Drivers](https://askubuntu.com/questions/55868/installing-broadcom-wireless-drivers/60395#60395)
- **Playing video** - you probably need the correct codec for the sound-track, try again after installing the 'restricted extras'

  ```
  sudo apt update
  sudo apt install ubuntu-restricted-extras
  ```

  It is also possible that you need to tweak the settings for the audio system with

  ```
  pavucontrol
  ```

Comment: I got an error.

depmod...(bad exit status: 135)

DKMS: uninstall completed.
Error! Problems with depmod detected.  Automatically uninstalling this module.
DKMS: Install Failed (depmod problems).  Module rolled back to built state.
dpkg: error processing package bcmwl-kernel-source (--configure):
 installed bcmwl-kernel-source package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 6
Errors were encountered while processing:
 bcmwl-kernel-source
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)

Comment: Did you find your Broadcom model ID in the list in the link in my answer? And it did not work with the driver suggested?

Comment: I can't sudo apt upgrade to move on

Comment: Now I searched and solved the problem for sound and upgrading the system. But I couldn't know the right package to instal as my PCI.ID is [14e4:4727] (rev 01) and I'm using Ubuntu 18.04, It's special case #1 but I don't know what should I do?

Comment: I found an answer with repetition 3 and it worked for me. Thanks.

Comment: Congratulations @SaraShokry :-) Please edit your original question to describe your solution. It can be useful for other people.